# Is there any way to fire a oracle query on the basis of query result

Tags: oracle11g

Is there any way to fire a oracle query on the basis of query result.
eg: select * from abc where col1='123', if the above query does not return result then change col1='abc' with single query

Thanks,
Husein

Comment: are the values taken from another table? like '123' taken from another table column?

Comment: no the values are user entered. I want to fire query for a particular customer if no rows are return then change customer value to 'standard'

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure insert_if_null(p_find IN varchar2)
as
v_count number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) 
   into v_count
  from table
  where col1 = p_find;

  if v_count = 0 then   -- means no data found while using your filter
   update table         
    set col1 = p_find;
  end if;
```

END;

The parameter in this procedure will depend on how many filters your planning to add and way to filter your `update statement.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I am looking for doing the task via oracle query

Comment: I want to fire query for a particular customer if no rows are return then change customer value in where clause to 'standard'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like

```
select *
  from (select a.*,
               rank() over (order by (case when col1 = 'standard'
                                           then 2
                                           else 1
                                        end)) rnk
          from abc a
         where col1 in ('123', 'standard'))
 where rnk = 1
```

If there is a row in `abc` with a `col1` value of "123", that row will have a `rnk` of 1 and will be returned.  If there is no `abc` row, the row with a `col1` value of "standard" will have a `rnk` of 1 (since it will be the only row) and will be returned.

From an efficiency standpoint, of course, it may be more efficient to do this in two operations rather than reading the "standard" row every time and sorting.

Comment: I am looking for single query where i can change the where clause if from first condition I dont get result then try with second. Eg: First I try searching rates for ABC customer if that is not available I can change where clause to Standard mean If ABC rates are not available in database search with Standard

Comment: @user1881820 - That is what I posted.  If that query isn't producing the results you want, posting a test case in your question would be helpful (i.e. post some DDL for a sample table, post some DML to insert enough data to produce the problem, post the results of running the query I posted against that data, tell us the results that you want from that data).